# Pretty printing an unreadable ClojureScript #js form

Tags: javascript, clojurescript, pretty-print

How to pretty-print a deeply-nested ClojureScript #js data structure that prints as an "unreadable form" on `(prn (js->clj some-form))`?

The unreadable parts seem to be object representations like  `"viewport" #<((123, 456), (678, 987))>}`. Alternatively, how do I strip out these unreadable forms so I can visualise the data structure?

I found [an article](http://proofbyexample.com/print-and-read-in-clojure.html) about printing Java objects, but surely there must be a simpler way?

Comment: Can you give an example of the #js data structure?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using the printer, use `(.log js/console x)`, it's way better at printing/inspecting JS objects than CLJS printer. It makes little sense to first convert the JS object to CLJS data just for printing.